# How to run external Ruby scripts from a Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, windows, google-chrome, sinatra

I have a Ruby script in a folder outside of my Sinatra application that I would like to run with a button click.

This is app.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :home
end

get '/launch_script' do
  system("ruby path\\to\\file\\delete_rows_csv.rb")
end
```

This is home.erb file:

```
<a href='/launch_script'> Launch a Script </a>
```

Am I supposed to load a filepath or require the file to get this to work?

---

This is the solution that worked great:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :home
end

get '/launch_script' do
  load 'path\\to\\file\\delete_rows_csv.rb'
end
```

Comment: Don't use `ruby path/to/file`. Use the absolute path to the Ruby interpreter you want to run the code. Without that the system has to search the environment PATH to find it, and if the PATH isn't including where Ruby lives the command will fail. Usually the appropriate path isn't set on a web server because the server runs as a restricted user.

Comment: agreed, but for the sake of not posting my absolute path in the post i left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require` or `require_relative` (depending if your file is located in a static place or relative to this file). Adding **.rb** is not required at the end either.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :home
end

get '/launch_script' do
  require 'path\\to\\file\\delete_rows_csv'
end
```

Comment: additionally, changing require to load and adding an rb made things smoother too

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about ``load`` entirely (which needs the full name but allows you to constantly call the script).